# How do you do EM algorithm for a factored model for a recommender system?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, maximum-likelihood, optimization, expectation-maximization

Let $X$ be a $n \times d$ matrix with users as rows and movies as columns. Each user is a single row $x^{(u)} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ (i.e. for user u there are at most d ratings for the d movies).

Also assume that each user is a mixture of type. As in:

$$P(x^{(u)} ; \theta) = \sum^K_{k=1}p(k) p(x^{(u)} | k; \theta)$$

There might be $K$ types ${1, ... , K}$, each corresponding to the type of user we have. Say that we have a user that tends to be romantic and hence he/she would tend to give high ratings to things like Titanic or the notebook. Hence, we will assume that given the type of user $j$ he is, then, the rating that he gives the movies are independent given his/her type. i.e. the probability of getting certain ratings for user $x^{(u)}$ factors as follows given he/she is of type j:

$$ P(x^{(u)} | k; \theta) = \Pi^{d}_{l = 1} p( x^{(u)}_{l} | k; \theta)$$

Notice that this is a simple naive-bayes model. Also, given the type, all users have the same probability of given a rating, i.e.:

$$ p( x^{(u)}_{l} | k; \theta) = \theta_{l | k}(x^{(u)}_{l}|k) =Pr[Rating \ moive \ l = x^{(u)}_{l} | user \ type \ k]$$

Hence, if we try to maximize the likelihood of this we get:

$$ \mathcal{L}(\theta) = Pr[Data; \theta] = \Pi^n_{u=1} p(x^{(t)} ; \theta) = \Pi^n_{u=1} \sum^{K}_{k} p(k) p( x^{(u)}_{l} | k; \theta)$$

Making it a log likelihood we get:

$$l(\theta) = \sum^n_{u=1} \log\sum^{K}_{k} p(k) p( x^{(u)}_{l} | k; \theta)$$

I was trying to maximize this log-likelihood with the EM algorithm and was planning on doing it as follows:

1. E-Step: Simply compute the posterior (i.e. soft counts) with the current model. i.e. compute:

$$P(j | u) = Pr[User \ is \ of \ type \ j | user \ u] = p(j|u) = \frac{p(j)p(x^{(u)} | j ; \theta )}{p(x^{u}; \theta)}$$

1. M-step: update the parameters based on how the new soft counts changed (i.e. the re-assignment of soft-clustering):

$$\hat n_{j} = \sum^{n}_{u=1} p(j|u)$$

$$ \hat p_j = \frac{\hat n_i}{n}$$

$ \hat n_{i,j}(r,j) $ = "expect number of ratings of value $r$ movie $i$ got from user type $j$"

$$\hat \theta_{i | j} = \frac{\hat n_{i,j}}{\hat n_j}$$

I think this is the correct E and M steps to do the correct EM on this model, however, I was unsure of 2 things:

1. Wanted to double check with the community if indeed this was the correct EM algorithm for this model.
2. How to compute $ \hat n_{i,j}(r,j) $. I am unsure how to compute it given my posterior.

With those two details check, I think i'd be ready to use it!

---

I was thinking was looking at the equations that Dafne Koller's PGM book has book but was unsure if the corresponded to the naive-bayes mixture model I described above as in:

$P(x^{(u)} ; \theta) = \sum^K_{k=1}p(k) p(x^{(u)} | k; \theta)$

I think one way of expressing the EM is as follows:

$$ P_k(k) = \theta^{(i+1)}_c = \frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{t=1}p_{k | t}(k|x^{(t)}, \theta^{(i)}$$

$$ P_{l|k}(x|k) = \theta^{(i+1)}_{l|k} = \frac{\sum^{n}_{t=1}p_{k | t}(k|x^{(t)}, \theta^{(t)})  \mathbb{1}\{ x^{(t)}_l = x_{l} \}   }{ \sum^{n}_{i=1} p_{k|t}(k | x^{(t)}, \theta^{(i)} })$$

Is this correct?

Comment: This is a mixture model, hence you should find plenty of literature on EM steps for mixtures...

Comment: @Xi'an Updated question. Found some candidate equations but I am not sure if they are correct since there is no derivation.